# Flutter bloc cual es la forma correcta de obtener datos que estan relacionados en distintos modelos

Tags: flutter, dart, relaciones, bloc

Estoy haciendo una app de venta de pedido offline, toda la data las descargo para después trabajar con ella.
Tengo los siguientes modelos, a manera de ejemplo
Estoy trabajando con flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

import 'package:denmob/models/base_model.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'Producto_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Producto extends Equatable with BaseModel {
 @HiveField(0)
 final int id;
 @HiveField(1)
 final String name;
 @HiveField(2)
 final int prov_id; //este el el id del proveedor
}


import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

import 'package:denmob/models/base_model.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'Proveedor_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Proveedor extends Equatable with BaseModel{
 @HiveField(0)
final int id;
 @HiveField(1)
final String name;
}
```

Ahora los datos los estoy manejando con bloc, y sí puedo consultar todos los registros,
lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma en pantalla products_scren.dart
Dentro del body de un scaffold pongo esto.

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';//en la cabecera

         BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is ProductImporting) {
              return const Text('Cargando productos, espere');
            }
            if (state is ProductLoading) {
              return const Text('Loadingggggg');
            }
            if (state is ProductLoaded) {
              List<Product> products = state.products
               return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: products.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                     Producto product = products[index];
                     return ListTile(
                      title: Text(product.name),
                      subtitle: Text(product.prov_id),
                     )
                  }   
               )
            }
            return const Text('prueba');
          },
        ),
```

El el subtitle de ListTile quisiera mostrar el nombre del proveedor,
no se cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo, puedo ponerle el BlocBuilder de proveedores,
buscar id proveedor y listo. pero no se si es la mejor forma.
Estoy usando hive y he visto que tienen relaciones
he aquí el articulo
https://developerb2.medium.com/relationships-in-hive-flutter-cb8cadf05c06

Adaptando el ejemplo
tengo que poner esto en mi clase producto

```
class Cliente extends HiveObject implements Equatable, BaseModel {
```

Esto me genera un warning en el linter

```
This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: HiveObjectMixin._box, HiveObjectMixin._keydartmust_be_immutable
```

y a su vez esta me obliga a sobrescribir el siguiente metodo de Equatable

```
@override
  // TODO: implement stringify
  bool? get stringify => throw UnimplementedError();
```

Estoy nunca he tenido que tocar, el temor es que si implento eso puedo causar errores inesperados.

Alguna recomendación por favor.

Datos adicionales:
Configuración de los boxes

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  Intl.defaultLocale = 'es_PE';
  initializeDateFormatting('es_PE', null);
  Hive.registerAdapter(ProductAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(ClienteAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(OfertaAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(ProveedorAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(ZonaAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(VendedorAdapter());

  final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  BoxCollection collection = await BoxCollection.open(
    'DenDB',
    {
      DenBoxNameTypes.product.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.cliente.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.oferta.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.proveedor.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.vendedor.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.zona.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.carrito.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.pedido.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.user.name,
      DenBoxNameTypes.category.name,
    },
    path: directory.path,
    // key: HiveCipher(),
  );


  runApp(MyApp(collection: collection, documentDirectory: directory));
}
```

y despues los uso dentro de los repositorios

```
CollectionBox box = await _localStorageRepository
          .openCollectionBox(DenBoxNameTypes.product);
Map<String, dynamic> productsHiveCollection = await box.getAllValues();
    List<Product> products =
        List<Product>.from(productsHiveCollection.values).toList();
    return products;
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás almacenando los datos en Hive? ¿Podrías poner la configuración de las boxes?

Comment: Hola @Manuel acabo de editar la pregunta añadiendo la configuración de los boxes como lo pediste, haber ojala puedas ayudarme, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, por partes. La pregunta no es específica, estás preguntando más de una cosa. Y en SOes, creo que va contra las normas.

Para el tema de obtener el nombre de los proveedores yo veo dos opciones posibles.

La primera es desnormalizando la base de datos. Hive es una base de datos no relacional. Por tanto, relacionar tablas, puede llegar a ser más engorroso. En su lugar, en en vez de tener que buscar en diversas tablas, haz que tus modelos tengan todos los datos que vayan a necesitar; si uno de esos datos es el nombre del proveedor, pues que lo tenga como un atributo.

La otra opción, sería que con el id del proveedor, que lo tienes en el producto, hagas una segunda llamada a la base de datos para obtener el nombre del proveedor.

Ahora el warning `This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: HiveObjectMixin._box, HiveObjectMixin._keydartmust_be_immutable`

En principio, no tienes que preocuparte por este warning. Es cierto que no es lo más recomendado tenerlo, pero tampoco es algo grave. Si te molesta verlo, ponle algún ignore al linter y ya está.

Y sobre `bool? get stringify => throw UnimplementedError()` Ponlo en true si quieres que equatable te genere un toString teniendo en cuenta la propiedad `props` y en false si no quieres.

Comment: Ok Manuel muchas gracias, creo que la segunda opción me parece mejor para mi caso, 
Muchas gracias

Comment: Sí te ha ayudado la respuesta, recuerda marcarla como la correcta. Gracias!

Comment: Hola Manuel, disculpa la ignorancia pero no encuentro la forma de marcar la respuesta como correcta, tengo reputación de 11, soy nuevo en esto. saludos

Comment: Buenas. No te preocupes. Todos hemos sido nuevos. En mi respuesta. Hay un icono de tick/check justo en el borde superior izquierdo de mi respuesta, junto a un 0 y dos flechas verticales. Aquí puedes ver una imagen y leer un poco sobre el tema: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: Si ya está.  No pensé que era un botón. Jeje ya está.saludos